# Android - How to define backup content rules to include only shared preferences

Tags: android, backup

I want to configure auto backup in my android app. The data hold by the app are too big (above 25MB) and I need to tell auto-backup mechanism to store only Shared Preferences data.

In AndroidManifest.xml, I added the line:

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules"
```

and in this xml file I want to exclude data like file, external and root. The example code can looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <full-backup-content>
   <exclude domain="root"
    path=" ??? " />
</full-backup-content>
```

And I have no idea how to fill the *path* property. Also when excluding file or external. My app uses storage in external storage directory and I want to exclude it also. How should I define the *path* property?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but
from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles

> By default, the system backs up almost all app data. For more
>   information, see Files that are backed up. This section shows you how
>   to define custom XML rules to control what gets backed up.
>
> Specifies a file or folder to backup. By default, Auto Backup includes
>   almost all app files. If you specify an  element, the system
>   **no longer includes any files** by default and backs up only the files specified. To include multiple files, use multiple 
>   elements.

So, you can use  instead of . I think, this is better solution than you list excluded files.